# 404 Error when trying to Post or Get RestController when webservice and client are on a different port

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I am using Spring-boot and Angular 2; The frontend and backend are running on different ports. When I check the URL with `Advanced REST Client` (google chrome plug-in) I get a 404 for `http://localhost:4000/user/register` and when I enter the information in the frontend nothing happens.

Web service configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {

    @Component
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

        public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) {
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)req;
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, x-requested-with, accept, Authorization, Content-Type");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
            if (!request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
                try {
                    chain.doFilter(req, res);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("IO Exception in CorsFilter: "+e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ServletException e) {
                    System.out.println("Servlet Exception is CorFilter "+e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

        public void destroy() {}

    }

}
```

The above is how I configured the backend.

I am trying to register a new `user` (Angular 2)

```
@Injectable()
export class RegisterService {

    constructor (private http:Http) { }

    sendUser (newUser: RegisterModel) {
        let url = "http://localhost:4000/user/register";
        let header = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

        return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(newUser),{headers: header});
    }
}
```

And it's component:

```
@Component ({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'register',
    templateUrl: './register.html'
})
export class RegisterComponent {

    newUser: RegisterModel = new RegisterModel();

    constructor (private registerService: RegisterService){

    }

    onSubmit() {
        this.registerService.sendUser(this.newUser).subscribe(
            data => {
                this.newUser = new RegisterModel();
                console.log("New user was created.")
            },
            error => console.log(error)
        );
    }
}
```

Restfull service

```
@RestController("/user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public User registerUser(@RequestBody User user){

        System.out.println("YAY-----------"+user.getFirstName());
        return userService.save(user);
    }



}
```

Nothing prints out and no error is given.

In my application.properties I have

`server.port=4000`

The pages render but it seems the backend is unresponsive.

I post also posted it in GIT if anyone wants to look.

[Git Hub link](https://github.com/drewjocham/AngularIssue.git)

---------------------Update 1--------------------

I have updated my SecurityConfig to:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/").permitAll().and()
            .logout().permitAll();

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/user/register")
            .permitAll().anyRequest().anonymous();

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/")
            .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.formLogin().loginPage("/")
            .permitAll().and().logout().permitAll();

    }

}
```

2) I also deleted the `pom file` in the `frontend` directory.

**Result:** I now get a `The requested URL can't be reached` when I use `Advanced REST client` (google chrome plug-in).

Updated it on GIT.

Comment: your project's parent pom on github contains errors. (1) type must be "pom", not "war".  (2) line 56 contains garbage text "rc.6" which makes the xml invalid.   + a unit test fails a compile time (RequestDemoApplicationTests.java)

Comment: + your angular/npm project ALSO inherits spring boot and defines the spring-boot-plugin (+ the one in the backend project) which cause spring boot to look for 2 main classes and throw this at build time: "Unable to find main class". Solution: your frontend project is a javascript project, why does it have a pom with spring-boot dependencies ?

Comment: There's a lot to fix in your project's pom before even getting to your error. Surely, you did not build your project using maven and you are only building/running it from intellij ?

Comment: + your application.properties (on github) does NOT contain server.port=4000

Comment: I fixed all issues so that it builds. I was then able to launch it ("mvn spring-boot:run" + "npm start"). I posted an answer to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Security config redirect to root => 404 error

I assume you are sending the `register` request before being authenticated ? Your security configuration redirects all requests to `/`, which isn't served on the backend side. So it isn't found and you receive a `404`.

#### Your security configuration

This is your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`'s security configuration:

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
    .formLogin().loginPage("/").permitAll().and()
    .logout().permitAll();
```

#### Allow anonymous to send the `register` request

You may change the security config to this, to let `register` go through before being authenticated:

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/user/register")
    .permitAll().anyRequest().anonymous();

http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/")
   .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();

http.formLogin().loginPage("/")
    .permitAll().and().logout().permitAll();
```

Basically, allow `anonymous` to send the register request.

#### Other errors in your project (also highlighted in the `comments` section)

- parent pom must be of type 'pom'
- line 56 of parent pom contains an error
- your frontend pom should not include spring-boot (which causes spring boot to look for 2 main-classes and fail)

---

> ## Update after comments

#### (1) UserController

Your UserController does not have any mapping defined. You mistakenly used `@RestController("/user")`, but it should rather be:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {
```

#### (2) SecurityConfig

You still have left over from your previous configuration in SecurityConfig:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
        .formLogin().loginPage("/").permitAll().and()
        .logout().permitAll();

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/user/register")
        .permitAll().anyRequest().anonymous();

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/")
        .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();

    http.formLogin().loginPage("/")
        .permitAll().and().logout().permitAll();    
}
```

**change it to:**

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/user/register")
        .permitAll().anyRequest().anonymous();

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/")
        .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();

    http.formLogin().loginPage("/")
        .permitAll().and().logout().permitAll();
}
```

The first line disables csrf (Cross-Site Request Forgery). Now, I'm not knowledgeable enough on the subject to give you an explanation, but if you don't disable it, you'll get 403 forbidden responses. I suggest you disable it and go back to this later when your current issue is fixed.

---

That's it, your backend will receive and respond to the /user/register request (and I can see the frontend's log in the console: "New user was created".

> EDIT October 18th

I cloned your project and it worked. Here are the **exact** steps I did:

- Opened a terminal and typed `git clone https://github.com/drewjocham/AngularIssue.git`
- Fixed RequestDemoApplicationTests's package from `test.java.com.request` to `com.request`
- Opened a terminal into `AngularIssue\backend`
- Typed `mvn clean install`
- Typed `mvn spring-boot:run` (the backend now runs)
- Opened another terminal into `AngularIssue\frontend`
- Typed `npm install`
- Typed `npm start` (the frontend now runs)
- Opened `http://localhost:3000` in chrome
- Opened the `inspect->console` view in chrome
- Filled the register form and clicked **submit**
- Chrome's console shows `New user was created.`
- Backend's terminal shows `YAY-----------a`

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort!

1) I made the above changes and it resulted in `The requested URL can't be reached.` via the google REST client...

2) I deleted the pom file in the frontend.

3) I am running the project in intellij via the embedded tomcat for now yes.

4) Not sure why applications.properties did not update when I made the change and reflect on git.

5) Thank you for the advice and I am updating my project on git.

Comment: Could you update your question with your error ? Where do you see "The requested URL can't be reached." error ? What url is causing this error ? In your browser, what can you see in the "inspect" view ? Do you see the "Yay" log in your spring boot controller ?

Comment: Updating question now and I see the error with Advanced REST client (google plug in with Google Chrome). I do not see anything in the console on my IDE.

Comment: Update complete. Thank you very much for the help, it's really appreciated!

Comment: Updated the answer - see the second part of the answer "update after comments"

Comment: I am doing what you are suggesting and it is still not working. Would you like to continue this in chat. Sorry for the late reply but I had several bugs at work I was working on. This is a personal project to learn and really appreciate your help. GIT updated.

Comment: I re-cloned your project, and it worked. I updated the answer with the exact steps I did!